# is it bad practice to have a get and set method combined into one method

Tags: java, design-patterns, netbeans, setter, getter

Here's my speaker class:

```
public class Speaker {
    private boolean isConnected;
    Speaker() {
    }
    //the method to change connection status and return it
    // it's setting and getting the state at the same time
    public boolean changeConnectionStatus(boolean isConnected) {
        this.isConnected = isConnected;
        return isConnected;
    }
    public static void main(String[] arg) {
        Speaker jamPlus = new Speaker();
        boolean connectionStatus = jamPlus.changeConnectionStatus(true);
    }
}
```

I thought it was a good idea at first to combine them but i'm sure it's not proper convention
also this kinda brings me off-topic to a different convention question. what
type of code should i throw into the main method? i'm %95 positive i should put the "boolean connectionStatus = etc..." in a separate method by itself?

Comment: how do you get the value back? the one that is currently there.

Comment: What's the point in returning the value passed to the method? It would make sense to return the original value.

Answer (score 4):

It is not a good practice (not at all).
What would you do if you'd like just to get the value (supposing the field is private)?
You'd have to pass a parameter and by doing that you'll have a 50% chance of getting the wrong answer.

Answer (score 1):

**So, did I get voted down for saying it's a bad practice, or for answering the question the OP asked even though I consider it a bad practice???**

Personally, the only major app I've seen do this is jQuery.  I've never seen anyone do it in .NET...and I'm guessing it would be rare in Java as well.

This is somewhat subjective, so you might get voted down a bit for asking something that doesn't have a definitive answer...but best practice is, typically, to separate your get (returns value) from your set (void or chain) methods.  Anything like what you have above makes the usage confusing.  If I type a method changeConnectionStatus, I'm expecting only to change it, not to get the value.  I would look for a getIsConnected method to read the value...and in absence of finding it, I would have to refer to your documentation just in order to figure out that you are re-using the same method for both...and if I have to refer to your documentation for something as simple as that...seems like a code smell.

So, I would avoid it...but again, subjective...jQuery does do it, and lots of people like jQuery...the main key is consistency.  Don't call it changeConnectionStatus because the word "change" doesn't sound like getting data...call it isConnected()...so:

```
public boolean isConnected(boolean isConnected)
{
    this.isConnected = isConnected;
    return this.isConnected;
}
public boolean isConnected()
{
    return this.isConnected;
}
```

Comment: thanks kevin i was a bit fuzzy too about it but i saw that it worked so WHY NOT! right lol i have to agree with what you're saying now that i think about it.

Comment: @BryanMills, it's a bit tough, but always try to put yourself in the place of someone else using your code :-p ... because even if it makes sense to you right now...in 6 months you're going to come back to the code and say WTH?

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't work. If you have a `set` method that sets the "property" then you expect:

1. the property/field to be set;
2. an exception to be thrown.

In the first case you just have to return the same value as that you are setting. This value you already know. In the second case: if an exception is thrown the original value will remain.

You could have a `set` method that returns a value *in addition* to a `get` method. This *could* make sense in case *method chaining* is used. This of course is of little value for `boolean` return values.

You would always have to program a `get` method (not shown in your example), otherwise you are left without a `get` function as the only way to retrieve the field value is to call `set`, which already modifies the value. Kind of a quantum field really, each time you are trying to read it you change the value.

Answer (score 0):

Generally not the convention: getters and setters are the norm

What you could do, however, is overload methods: if no param is passed, gets, if param is passed, sets. Although, I do not see the point in that...

**Or, you could have a second argument that is another boolean or an int, and if true/1, is getter, else if false/0, is setter.**